# How to Set RelayState in SAMLEntryPoint

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, single-sign-on, spring-saml

I have my EntryPoint class as follows, but what is the exact value to be set in the relaystate, any example. I want to fetch the URL parameter values requested before authenticating.

```
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLMessageContext;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions;

public class SamlLoginEntryPoint extends SAMLEntryPoint{

    protected WebSSOProfileOptions getProfileOptions(SAMLMessageContext context, AuthenticationException exception) throws MetadataProviderException {

        System.out.println("inside entrypoint");
        WebSSOProfileOptions ssoProfileOptions;
        if (defaultOptions != null) {
            System.out.println("in if");
            ssoProfileOptions = defaultOptions.clone();
            ssoProfileOptions.setRelayState("");
            System.out.println("relaystate:"+ssoProfileOptions.getRelayState());
        } else {
            System.out.println("in else");
            ssoProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
            ssoProfileOptions.setRelayState("");
        }

        return ssoProfileOptions;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dalu: I'm not sure if that is safe against race conditions. `SAMLEntryPoint` normally is a singleton bean.

Consider the scenario where `User A` wants to login with `URL X`, but at the same time `User B` logs in with `URL Y` (after A called `commence()`, but before he called `getProfileOptions`.

The solution would be to not define `private String relayState;` as a global variable, but to use a session-based storage instead.

Answer (score -1):

Override the commence() method of SAMLEntryPoint class and get the request parameter from the request object .

So my implementation looks like this :

```
public class CustomMFASamlEntryPoint extends SAMLEntryPoint {
   private String relayState;

   @Override 
   public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
       //read your request parameter
       setRelayState(request.getParameter("request-param-for-relaystate"));
       super.commence(request, response, authenticationException);
   }

   @Override
   protected WebSSOProfileOptions getProfileOptions(SAMLMessageContext samlMessageContext, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws MetadataProviderException {
       //set the relayState to your SAML message context
       samlMessageContext.setRelayState(getRelayState());
       return super.getProfileOptions(samlMessageContext, authenticationException);
   }

   private void setRelayState(String relayState) {
       this.relayState = relayState;
   }

   private String getRelayState() {
       return relayState;
   }
}
```